# Coverity scan for .Netstandard 2.1 library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, coverity, sast

I am trying to use Coverity with my .NetStandard2.1 library.
using commands like:

```
set COVERITY_PATH="C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\cov-analysis-win64-8.5.0\bin"
set PATH=%PATH%;%COVERITY_PATH%
cov-configure --cs
cov-build --dir MY_EMIT_DIR dotnet build || (echo build failed )
echo "build successfully!!"
cov-analyze --dir MY_EMIT_DIR
cov-commit-defects --dir MY_EMIT_DIR --host 10.ccc.aaa.bbb --user xxxxx --password xxxxx --stream CSProject
```

After running the command getting the warning and error:

> [WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with
> your configuration or because no files were actually compiled by your
> build command. Please make sure you have configured the compilers
> actually used in the compilation.  For more details, please look at:
> C:/xxx/Src/MY_EMIT_DIR/build-log.txt

```
C:\xxx\Src>cov-analyze --dir MY_EMIT_DIR
Coverity Static Analysis version 8.5.0 on Windows 10 (Unknown Edition number 121), 64-bit (build 19042)
Internal version numbers: c8d197a567 p-kent-push-26368.915

Using 1 worker as limited by CPU(s)
Looking for translation units
Error: intermediate directory contains no translation units.
```

I also tried to set the compiler explicitly like,

```
cov-configure --compiler "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe"
```